# Django 'WSGIRequest' object is not callable

Tags: django

I'm working on an app and I'm trying to display all my users but I get this error

```
TypeError at /everyone/
'WSGIRequest' object is not callable

File "/home/snake/mysite/pet/views.py" in Everyone
  14.   return HttpResponseRedirect(request('world:Profile'))
Exception Type: TypeError at /everyone/
Exception Value: 'WSGIRequest' object is not callable
```

I did a lookup at my shell prompt and it successfully work but when I implement as a function into my views.py why do I get this error.

everyone = Person.objects.all()
print everyone
< sam > < amy >

My views.py

```
def Everyone(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request('world:Profile'))
    everyone =Person.objects.all()
        return render(request,'everyone.html',{'everyone':everyone})
```

My models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/",blank=True,null=True)
```

My everyone.html

```
{% for one in everyone %}
{{one.name}}
{{one.user.username}}
{% endfor %]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
...
return HttpResponseRedirect(request('world:Profile'))
...
```

You're using the request object as a callable, which it isn't. You probably wanted to call the `reverse` function.

Comment: I see the mistake . I over looked it so much . I forgot to reverse it

Comment: No problem, glad to help :3

Comment: I had the same error, turned out I was using `request` instead of `reverse`

Answer (score 0):

return HttpResponseRedirect(request,'world:Profile')

Test remove braces around the 'world:Profile'.